# Response.json() bind to single object using interface - RxJs/Observable fails

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-template, rxjs5

This scenario works fine when the RESTful API returns a JSON array - but the web method I'm calling returns a single JSON object - and so the code has been converted to map a single object from `<IRegistration[]> to <IRegistration>` all the way up the stack.

This fails and the Chrome console returns an error showing the app could not find either of the mapped fields in the HTML

The HTML

```
{{myobject.productId}}
{{myobject.productName}}
```

The JSON

```
{
  "productId": 1,
  "productName": "My Field Value"
}
```

The Interface

```
export interface IRegistration {
    productId: number;
    productName: string;
}
```

The observable

```
getRegistration(): Observable<IRegistration> {
    return this._http.get(this._svcURL)
        .map((response: Response) => <IRegistration>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('ALL: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The client component

```
myobject: IRegistration;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this._registrationService.getRegistration().subscribe(
        reg => this.myobject= reg,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
}
```

The error

```
 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'productId' of undefined in [
{{myobject.productId}}
{{myobject.productName}}

 in SearchComponent@0:0]
```

The debugging I've done points to the response.json() in the observable failing to map correctly to the IRegistration - I can't seem to find the correct syntax?

Comment: Why you think the problem is in `map()`? What does the `.do()` print? Also, I think the `<IRegistration>` in `map()` is redundant, TypeScript compiler it can't check correct type from `json()` because it can be anything so it will never raise any error.

Comment: hmmm.. <IRegistration[]> works fine when there is an array of JSON - in this Angular2 app the map() works out how to populate the strong type ok - it goes bad when I remove the [] and adjust everything else - the .do() just dumps the JSON to console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine, I think the problem is that you don't initialize the `myobject: IRegistration;` before using it.

The [doc for lifecycle hook `ngOnInit()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) says:

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.

The data is displayed before the HTTP call returns any result so `myobject` is undefined when Angular is trying to render it.

You can use `?` to ignore undefined properties such as `{{ myobject?.productId }}` or initialize the property first `myobject: IRegistration = <IRegistration>{};`.

Comment: that was a surprise - this.myobject - is being setup by the observable listener ok - but clearly not initialised in time for the page - the ?null check just fixes it for now - thanks